# zClip not showing `title` attribute

Tags: jquery, zclip

I have the following code:

```
<script>
    $('a#control_copy').zclip({
        path:'ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:function(){return $('#translate_result').text() }
    });
</script>
<div id="translate_result">

</div><br>
<div id="translate_controls">
    <a id="control_copy" title="Copy result to clipboard."><img src="controls/copy.png"/></a>
</div>
```

But when I add a `title` attribute the title doesn't show. What do you think I can do about this?

Comment: It's because the `<a>` is not being directly hovered, but i'm not sure how to combat that. If you're using jQuery UI, their tooltip widget might be of use.

Comment: @Scimonster Or I would just use Tipr.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's because the `<a>` tag is not being directly hovered. So I started using [Tipr](http://www.tipue.com/tipr).